# How can I store an audio file in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to store an audio file in an iPhone app.

Is it possible to do this with SQLite?

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Could you specify where you are getting these audio files? Are they going to be on the device already, will they be changing throughout the use of the app, or will you be downloading them from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the audio data using a `BLOB` in sqlite

*Edit:*

You can for instance define the following in your database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE audio (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    rawaudio BLOB
);
```

In your code you will then just have to store the raw data of your audio into the `rawaudio` field in the `audio` table.

Comment: No. I dont know what is blob.. Is there a way to use the store audio file..? I am trying to record audio file than dynamically that file want to be save in dsatabase.. Still yat not success to do this.. Plz if you have idea than reply and suggest me which one is better.. Regards

Comment: BLOB stands for Binary Large OBject. I've edited my answer to give a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use BLOB data type if you want to store the audio file in the SQLite.

You could also just store it in a directory and access it directly.

It depends how you want to use your audio file and if it might change often.

Comment: No. I dont know what is blob.. Is there a way to use the store audio file..? I am trying to record audio file than dynamically that file want to be save in dsatabase.. Still yat not success to do this.. Plz if you have any idea or blob basic tutorial than reply and suggest me which one is better.. Regards

Comment: Just to clairify, a BLOB is a [Binary Large Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object)

Comment: As csaunders said, blob is just a binary largo object (e.g. bits one after the other). You can retreive is using NSData object and after create whatever it should be from it (using imageWithData: for example)

Answer (score 1):

Do you WANT to use SQLite, or is that a stab at answering the main question? Because if "with SQLite" isn't a requirement, this is simple. Just stick the file in your "Resources" group in XCode. It'll end up in your application bundle.

Comment: Ya I m using sqlite. And i am trying to record audio dynamically after that file want to be save in dsatabase.. Still yat not success to do this.. Plz if you have idea than reply and suggest me which one is better.. Regards

Comment: Why not save the file in your app's directory and save a path to it in the database? Lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but probably not the best idea. Instead, add the file as a resource in the application, and then store the **name** of the file in the DB, not the file itself. That way, you can update the file whenever and however you want.

Comment: yup, I have done like that to store recorded file in app resource after that done it. But after  that i can not get it properly..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this while building the app or while it is running?

Cocoa-Touch provides persistence support through SQLite or Core-Data if you want to look at those technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your audio files, BLOBs could work or you could just write them to disk and keep track of them somewhere.

I had a similar issue where I needed to pull down remote audio files and store them on the device.  I used CoreData for keeping a searchable index of where all the files were stored then would just open up the file using the path that was provided for that core data item.

Core Data is a bit wonky to work with at first, but once you wrap your head around it is pretty nice.  I used [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) for all of my models, which will run scripts on your core data models to create all the boilerplate code for you.

Comment: Mogenerator is the basic tutorial for blob tech..?

Comment: I've found it makes using CoreData easier, which is why I suggested it.